# Crear un archivo json a partir de diccionarios en otro archivo python

Tags: python, json, micropython

Estoy trabajando en un microcontrolador con micropython y una de las acciones que más hago es leer y escribir archivos json. El problema que estoy teniendo es que a veces se corrompen, y si esto pasa todo el sistema deja de funcionar.

Para solucionar esto lo que hago es que englobo la acción de lectura/escritura dentro de un `try/except` y en caso de error genero de nuevo el archivo a costa de perder los datos que estuvieran (es asumible). La cosa es que el proyecto crece y me gustaría unificar en único punto el comprobar si hay json corruptos y en ese caso crearlos de nuevo.

Además, ya que los json se pueden corromper había pensado tener un fichero `.py` con diccionarios equivalente a cada json y cuando estos estén corruptos, hacer la copia de aquí.

Si suponemos tengo el fichero `json_data.py` con el siguiente diccionario:

```
dataframe = {
  "data": []
}
```

Yo querría en mi `boot.py` (el cual se ejecuta una sola vez al arrancar el programa) hacer dicha comprobación de errores.

Si yo hago lo siguiente me funciona correcto y me imprime el diccionario:

```
import json_data

print(json_data.dataframe)
```

La cosa es que pensaba tener una lista de todos mis archivos json e ir comprobando uno a uno, pero al hacer esto me da problemas pues si pongo `[dataframe]` me dice que la variable `dataframe` no la he declarado, si lo pongo como un `string` no puede llamar bien al diccionario pues no es el tipo de dato correcto. Si empleo `eval()` (siendo consciente que no es lo suyo) me da error.

```
import json_data

li = ['dataframe']
for f in li:
    print(json_data.eval(f))
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'eval'

Puede ser que emplee mal `eval`? O es que se hace de otra manera?

Mi idea final para comprobar el tema de errores (que aún no he podido probar) es esta:

```
myFiles = [file1, file2, file3]
for f in myFiles:
    try:
        _ = readJSON('f')
        # He creado una función de lectura de archivos json con las líneas típicas para que el código fuera menos denso.
    # Como realmente no pretendo actuar, guardo los datos en _
    except:
        data = json_data.f
        writeJSON('f', json.dumps(data))
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para acceder a los diccionarios externos?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, necesitas poder declarar variables a partir de strings. Esto se puede hacer con `exec`:

Por un lado he creado el fichero `prueba.py`:

```
var1 = 'Soy var1'
var2 = 'Y yo var2'
```

Y por otro `probando.py`:

```
import prueba

l = ['var1', 'var2']

for x in l:
    exec("%s = prueba.%s" % (x, x))

print("%s\n%s" % (var1, var2))
```

Salida:

```
Soy var1
Y yo var2
```

Answer (score 0):

la verdad es que no se si entendí tu planteo igual respondo lo que interpreté

Hay un diccionario en otro módulo le pongo algún dato:

```
dataframe = {"data":['archivo1.txt','archivo2.txt','archivo3.txt']}

import json_data as jd

lista= jd.dataframe.get('data')

for x in lista:
    print(x)
```

¿qué hice? simplemente tomé el valor de la clave que ya es una lista

Esto devuelve:

```
archivo1.txt
archivo2.txt
archivo3.txt
```